# Azure Website to use Classic Application Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm moving 10 sites to Azure Website(s), they need to use **Classic** Application Pipeline, **not integrated**.
How can I set that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently - you cannot modify any application pool settings of **Azure Websites** [for any Mode](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/how-to-scale-websites/) (*Free, Shared, or Reserved*). There are [few configuration settings](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/how-to-configure-websites/#howtochangeconfig) you can control for Azure Websites.

You will need to either use an **Azure VM** or **Azure Web Role**.